# Angular. What is the correct way of refresh token implementation?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

At the moment I'm having the problem with logic implementation.

I want to make the next thing:

When there is any **signed** (signed - means with JWT token provided, for authenticated users) request fired to the API backend, the API backend may return 401 JWT Token Expired. In this case, I want to make another call to refresh the JWT token and then (if successfull) - make the original request once again. If failed - redirect to login page.

The current problems with this implementation are:

1) refreshToken() is inside ApiService, but I think it should be inside AuthService, because it is related to authentication. But if I move the method - then I have to inject AuthService (which extends ApiService) inside ApiService, and here comes the deadloop problem + I don't know how to pass this argument in constructor for AuthService, to make the .super(args) call.

2) My code at the moment is not working, because of this part:

```
  this.refreshToken().toPromise().then(() => {
    if (request.data) {
      console.log('POST');
      return this[request.method](request.endpoint, request.data);
    } else {
      console.log('GET');
      return this[request.method](request.endpoint);
    }
  });
```

as the refreshToken is async, I cannot return (actually call) the original method. How should I deal with this?

My code example is below:

**DataService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { NotFoundError } from '../errors/response-errors/not-found-error';
import { BadRequest } from '../errors/response-errors/bad-request';
import { AppError } from '../errors/app-error';
import { Unauthorized } from '../errors/response-errors/unauthorized';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  protected lastRequest: any;

  constructor(private url: string, private http: Http) {}

  get(endpoint) {
    console.log('called get: ' + endpoint);
    console.log('THIS:', this);
    this.lastRequest = {
      'method': 'get',
      'endpoint': endpoint,
    };

    return this.http
    .get(this.url + endpoint, this.options)
    .map((response) => {
      const r = response.json();
      console.log('Response (get):');
      console.log(r);
      return r;
      // return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }

  post(endpoint, data) {
    console.log('called post: ' + endpoint);
    this.lastRequest = {
      'method': 'post',
      'endpoint': endpoint,
      'data': data
    };

    return this.http
      .post(this.url + endpoint, data, this.options)
      .map((response) => {
        const r = response.json();
        console.log('Response:');
        console.log(r);
        return r;
        // return response.json();
      })
      .catch(error => this.handleError(error));
  }

  get options() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
         return new RequestOptions({
           headers: headers
        });
    }

    return null;
  }

  protected handleError(error: Response): any {
    if (error.status === 400) {
      return Observable.throw(new BadRequest(error.json()));
    }

    if (error.status === 401) {
      return Observable.throw(new Unauthorized());
    }

    if (error.status === 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    }

    return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
  }
}
```

**ApiService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Unauthorized } from '../errors/response-errors/unauthorized';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService extends DataService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
      super('https://my-api-endpoint', http);
  }

  refreshToken()  {
    console.log('refreshToken clalled');
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    console.log('using refresh token:', refreshToken);
    if (refreshToken) {
      return this.post('/renew-access-token', {
        refresh_token: refreshToken
      })
      .map(response => {
        console.log('got refreshToken response:');
        console.log(response);
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.refresh_token);
      });
    }
  }

  protected handleError(error: Response) {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      const res: any = error.json();
      if (res && res.message === 'Expired JWT Token') {
          const request = this.lastRequest;
          console.log('last request:', request);
          this.refreshToken().toPromise().then(() => {
            if (request.data) {
              console.log('POST');
              return this[request.method](request.endpoint, request.data);
            } else {
              console.log('GET');
              return this[request.method](request.endpoint);
            }
          });
      }
      console.log('NO');
      return Observable.throw(new Unauthorized());
    }

    return super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

**TendersService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class TendersService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http);
  }

  getTenders(dateFrom, dateTo, status = 'actual', limit = 5, offset = 0) {

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('date_from', dateFrom);
    params.set('date_to', dateTo);
    params.set('status', status);
    params.set('limit', limit.toString());
    params.set('offset', offset.toString());

    return this.get('/tenders?' + params.toString());
  }
}
```

**AuthService**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired, JwtHelper } from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends ApiService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http);
  }

  login(credentials) {
    return this.post('/login', credentials)
    .map(response => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
      localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.refresh_token);
    });
  }

  logout() {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    if (refreshToken) {
      this.post('/logout', {
        refresh_token: refreshToken
      }).toPromise();
    }
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
  }
}
```

Comment: by the way - i think this is not a good idea to save refresh token in local storage...

Answer (score 0):

I think you could consider to use the dependency injection over the service inheritance. Moving methods such like "refreshToken" to AuthService is good idea, but you also should move the "handleError" method to the AuthService, because that method also should handle only authentication error and for example renew token or sign out user. So after that you do not need anymore to inherit form your ApiService, i do not quite understood it purpose at all.

After that, in your DataService you could just **inject** your AuthService (instead inheritance) and modify the sending request by adding authentication headers to the request. From my point of view, i think it is better to separate AuthService from DataService's.

A decent example already provided [here](http://%20https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular2-jwt-authentication-example/blob/master/app/_services/user.service.ts) on github.
[Link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/16/angular-2-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial#fake-backend-ts) to the complete guide.

Comment: I consider using HttpInterceptors, I think this is what I was looking for.